# skipwaiting() on updatefound getting my page into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, infinite-loop, reload

service worker file:

```
registration.onupdatefound = () => {
    const installingWorker = registration.installing;
    if (installingWorker == null) {
      return;
    }
    installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
      if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
          // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
          // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
          // content until all client tabs are closed.
          console.log(
            'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
              'tabs for this page are closed.
          );

          // Execute callback
          registration.postMessage({action: 'skipWaiting'})
          if (config && config.onUpdate) {
            config.onUpdate(registration);
          }
        } else {
          // At this point, everything has been precached.
          // It's the perfect time to display a
          // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
          console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

          // Execute callback
          if (config && config.onSuccess) {
            config.onSuccess(registration);
          }
        }
      }
    };
  };
}`
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
if (event.data.action === 'skipWaiting') {
  self.skipWaiting();
}
```

});

//listening in app.js controller change event

```
// reload once when the new Service Worker starts activating
var refreshing;
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange',
function() {
if (refreshing) return;
refreshing = true;
window.location.reload();
 }
);
```

what it actually does:

1. If it finds any update, sending a postMessage as skipWating
   2.Once the message recieved by listener , it calls the skipWaiting()
   3.then controllerchange event gets called where we refreshing the page.

Why it gets into infinite loop of reload()

Answer (score 0):

Your first bit of code, everything under `registration.onupdatefound`, shouldn't be in the service worker file. It should be in your web app's `window` context.

The bit that should be in your service worker file is:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.data.action === 'skipWaiting') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
}
```

There's documentation for another "recipe" that accomplishes this at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users. It uses the `workbox-window` library to simplify things a bit.